# Building Ruby extensions in C++ using Rice: How to transmit the pointer of Ruby method (callback) to C++ function?

Tags: c++, ruby, callback, asynccallback

I have pretty cool C++ library named [libcage](https://github.com/ytakano/libcage). I need methods of class in the library to call from Ruby script. **I am building Ruby extensions in C++ using [Rice](https://rubygems.org/gems/rice)**.

A method `join` from a class `cage` uses a **parameter as a pointer to the callback** function.
Simplified illustrative example usage the callback in C++:

```
/* File example.cpp */
#include <libcage/cage.hpp>

void joinCallback(bool joinResult) {
    // do something
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    libcage::cage *cage = new libcage::cage;
    cage->join("localhost", 80, &joinCallback);
}
/* End of file example.cpp */
```

After some event the `join` method will call `callback` function. This is no problem, but **I want the callback function define in Ruby!**

```
# File example.rb
require './rb_libcage'  # C++ extension library

def joinCallback(joinResult)
    # do something
end

cage = Cage.new
cage.join "localhost", 80, method(:joinCallback)
# End of file example.rb
```

This does not work now. **I don't know how to transmit the pointer of Ruby method to C++ function** via call parameter `callback_to_ruby` in sample below.

---

**EDIT:**

I have actually now this:

```
/* File rb_libcage.cpp */
#include "rice/Class.hpp"
#include "rice/Data_Type.hpp"
#include "rice/Constructor.hpp"

#include "cage.hpp"

Rice::Object __callback_to_ruby;
ID           __callback_id_to_ruby;

namespace {
    void c_callback(bool result)
    {
        if (result)
                    std::cout << "join: succeeded" << std::endl;
            else
                    std::cout << "join: failed" << std::endl;

            /* This does not work! */
            __callback_to_ruby.call(__callback_id_to_ruby,"AsyncCallback"); 
            /**
             * terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Rice::Exception'
             *  what():  undefined method `call' for "AsyncCallback":String
             * Aborted
         */
    }
    class Cage_wrapper
    {
        public:
            Cage_wrapper() : cage(new libcage::cage()) {}

            void join(std::string host, int port, Rice::Object callback_to_ruby) {
                __callback_to_ruby = callback_to_ruby;
                __callback_id_to_ruby = rb_intern("call");
                __callback_to_ruby.call(__callback_id_to_ruby,"test"); /* This works! */

                /* cage->join() will make another thread that will call ASYNCHRONOUSLY c_callback function */
                cage->join(host, port, &c_callback); 
            }
        private:
            libcage::cage *cage;
    };

    extern "C"
    void Init_rb_libcage(void)
    {
        RUBY_TRY
        {
            Rice::define_class<Cage_wrapper>("Cage")
                .define_constructor(Rice::Constructor<Cage_wrapper>())
                .define_method("join", &Cage_wrapper::join);
        }
        RUBY_CATCH
    }
} // namespace
/* End of file rb_libcage.cpp */
```

and Ruby script:

```
# File example.rb
require './rb_libcage'  # C++ extension library

ruby_callback = lambda {|x| print "From ruby script join result: ", x, "\n" }
cage = Cage.new
cage.join "localhost", 80, ruby_callback
puts 'After join'
# End of file example.rb
```

`rb_libcage.cpp` is compileable and run `example.rb` looks like this:

```
From ruby script join result: test
After join
join: succeeded
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Rice::Exception'
  what():  undefined method `call' for "AsyncCallback":String
Aborted
```

I can call synchronous callback but not asynchronous callback. It will lost context? How to successful call asynchronously ruby callback from C++ code?

Best regards,
Pawel

P.S.: I found useful [article about building Asynchronous callbacks in Ruby C extensions](http://burgestrand.se/articles/asynchronous-callbacks-in-ruby-c-extensions.html)

Comment: For starters, you are not passing a reference to the method – :callback is a symbol. Pass it proc (lambda) or block – you may be then able to yield it from native code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a ruby expert but I'm thinking Cage_wrapper.join method signature might want to look more like

```
void join(std::string host, int port, Rice::Object *ruby_proc)
```

You can use a ruby proc as the callback to the native library. i.e. The Rice::Object is the ruby proc.

Then at some point you are going to want to do a ruby_proc.call(). So you might need to wrap the the call to ruby_proc.call in a callback which is palatable to the native cage join.